# Unable to push MQ message from JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Tried with following approach using Java Request through Jmeter

[MQ_Error from JMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nirpF.png)

Comment: Srikanth, Can I know which Sampler are you using for this, If you need to send data to MQ (IBM Websphere MQ) we have separate sampler for that.

Comment: Hi Chandra Sekhar thanks for the reply. we are using Java Request for communicating with MQ

Comment: Can you brief your exact requirement

Comment: We are using the approach available in this link "https://github.com/JoseLuisSR/mqmeter" and using the Plugins provided in it into Jmeter.

Here,IBM MQ is in Cloud Environment.At first when we tried to connect to IBM MQ it was throwing "Host_Not_Available" error.
Then we approached IBM Support team they told that our IP address should be whitelisted by them which is done.

Again we tried but now it was different error "Connection_Broken". so they again sent us Server certificate which need to be added to our Keystore.

Comment: Keystore Approach we followed: Link: "https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/ghlgv/index.html"

1. First Command: keytool -genkey -alias keyAlias -keyalg RSA -keypass changeit -storepass changeit -keystore keystore.jks
2. Second Command: keytool -export -alias keyAlias-storepass changeit -file server.cer -keystore keystore.jks
3. Third Command: keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias keyAlias -file server.cer -keystore cacerts.jks -keypass changeit

Comment: while running the Jmeter script we are selecting it from "Option->SSL Manager->selecting .jks file generated".Now the key is loading successfully into Jmeter but we are getting the same error "Connection_Broken".

Answer (score 0):

As per [MQ connection is terminating with error code 2009](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mq-connection-terminating-error-code-2009) the reasons could be in:

1. A firewall that is terminating the connection
2. An IOException that causes the socket to be closed
3. An explicit action to cause the socket to be closed by one end
4. The queue manager is offline
5. The maximum number of channels allowed by the queue manager are open
6. A configuration problem in the Queue Connection Factory (QCF)

so follow this checklist, hopefully it will allow you to get to the bottom of the issue.

Also this `MQClientSampler` doesn't look familiar to me, you may need to reach out to the plugin developer/maintainer as it might be a bug in the plugin.

You can consider using [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [IBMMQ client libraries](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q128170_.htm) as an alternative solution, check out [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how/) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit easier to use Groovy script since it doesn't need to be pre-compiled like Java.  I made an example here that works with JMeter 5.3 and MQ9:

https://github.com/djangofan/jmeter-ibm-mq9